# Haskell List Comprehension creating function

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and am trying to learn the basics. I am having a hard time understanding how to manipulate the contents of a list.

Assume I have the following list and I would like to create a function to subtract 1 from every element in the list, where I can simply pass x to the function, how would this be done?

```
Prelude>let x = 1:2:3:4:5:[]
```

Something like:

```
Prelude>subtractOne(x)
```

Comment: Do you mean `Prelude> subtractOne x`? Remember that Haskell does *not* use parentheses with functions.

Comment: @Code-Guru, the expression `subtractOne(x)` is perfectly legal, though non-Haskellish

Comment: @Code-Guru, What about Curry functions named after the Haskell himself! they use parenthesis with functions and work %100 and are a part of Haskell.

Comment: @nameless I didn't know that. All the Haskell code I've read doesn't use parentheses, so I didn't consider whether or not it is legal. After thinking about it, I see *why* it works. I suspect that the parens simply surround the expression `x` and are *not* for a function call.

Comment: @MHZ I'm not sure what you mean by "Curry functions".

Comment: Also called Curried functions, see http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html

Comment: The parentheses in `add (x,y)` illustrate Haskell's pattern matching feature to extract the two elements of a 2-tuple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23605/discussion-between-code-guru-and-mhz)

Comment: Not really sure how your comment relates, see the documentation on haskell.org :)

Comment: @MHZ Do you mean the documentation that says that we can write an *un*curried function using a tuple? The example of a function which uses parentheses is `add (x, y)`. As I stated earlier, the parentheses here have nothing to do with function syntax. Rather they are the syntax for a tuple. It looks the same as a C-style function, but it isn't exactly. You will understand the difference as you learn about Haskell's type system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(You can write `1:2:3:4:5:[]` more simply as `[1,2,3,4,5]` or even `[1..5]`.)

### Comprehensions

You'd like to use list comprehensions, so here it is:

```
subtractOne xs = [ x-1 | x <- xs ]
```

Here I'm using `xs` to stand for the list I'm subtracting one from.

The first thing to notice is `x <- xs` which you can read as "`x` is taken from `xs`". This means we're going to take each of the numbers in `xs` in turn, and each time we'll call the number `x`.

`x-1` is the value we're calculating and returning for each `x`.

For more examples, here's one that adds one to each element `[x+1|x<-xs]` or squares each element `[x*x|x<-xs]`.

### More than one list

Let's take list comprehension a little further, to write a function that finds the squares then the cubes of the numbers we give it, so

```
> squaresAndCubes [1..5]
[1,4,9,16,25,1,8,27,64,125]
```

We need

```
squaresAndCubes xs = [x^p | p <- [2,3], x <- xs]
```

This means we take the powers `p` to be 2 then 3, and for each power we take all the `x`s from `xs`, and calculate `x` to the power `p` (`x^p`).

What happens if we do that the other way around?

```
squaresAndCubesTogether xs = = [x^p | x <- xs, p <- [2,3]]
```

We get

```
> squaresAndCubesTogether [1..5]
[1,1,4,8,9,27,16,64,25,125]
```

Which takes each `x` and then gives you the two powers of it straight after each other.

Conclusion - the order of the `<-` bits tells you the order of the output.

### Filtering

What if we wanted to only allow some answers?

Which numbers between 2 and 100 can be written as `x^y`?

```
> [x^y|x<-[2..100],y<-[2..100],x^y<100]
[4,8,16,32,64,9,27,81,16,64,25,36,49,64,81]
```

Here we allowed all `x` and all `y` as long as `x^y<100`.

---

Since we're doing exactly the same to each element, I'd write this in practice using `map`:

```
takeOne xs = map (subtract 1) xs
```

or shorter as

```
takeOne = map (subtract 1)
```

(I have to call it `subtract 1` because `- 1` would be parsed as negative 1.)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with the `map` function:

```
subtractOne = map (subtract 1)
```

The alternative solution with List Comprehensions is a little more verbose:

```
subtractOne xs = [ x - 1 | x <- xs ]
```

You may also want to add type annotations for clarity.

Comment: +1 Thank you! Can you please explain how the list comprehension works? how it reads? I am less concerned with the solution, and more with learning how to use list comprehension...

Comment: @MHZ, you can read it like this: "For each item `x` in `xs` evalutate the expression `x - 1` and combine the result of each evaluation in the new list."

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily with the `map` function, but I suspect you want to roll something yourself as a learning exercise. One way to do this in Haskell is to use recursion. This means you need to break the function into two cases. The first case is usually the base case for the simplest kind of input. For a list, this is an empty list `[]`. The result of subtracting one from all the elements of the empty list is clearly an empty list. In Haskell:

```
subtractOne [] = []
```

Now we need to consider the slightly more complex recursive case. For any list *other than* an empty list, we can look at the head and tail of the input list. We will subtract one from the head and then apply `subtractOne` to the rest of the list. Then we need to concatenate the results together to form a new list. In code, this looks like this:

```
subtractOne (x:xs) = (x - 1) : subtractOne xs
```

As I mentioned earlier, you can also do this with `map`. In fact, it is only one line and the preferred Haskellism. On the other hand, I think it is a very good idea to write your own functions which use explicit recursion in order to understand how it works. Eventually, you may even want to write your own `map` function for further practice.

Comment: +1 @Code-Guru Thank you! great explanation of recursion in Haskell, regardless of our 'curried function' differences;)

Answer (score 1):

`map (subtract 1) x` will work.

```
subtractOne = map (subtract 1)
```

The `map` function allows you to apply a function to each element of a list.